# Create a calendar event in device calendar not working in Google pixel

Tags: android-intent, xamarin.android

I try to create a event in android device its working in all the android device but not working in the Google pixcel device.

Please do the needfull

```
Android.Net.Uri EVENTS_URI = Android.Net.Uri.Parse("content://com.android.calendar/" + "events");
        ContentValues eventValues = new ContentValues();

        eventValues.Put(CalendarContract.Events.InterfaceConsts.CalendarId, 1);
        eventValues.Put(CalendarContract.Events.InterfaceConsts.Title, "Heading");
        eventValues.Put(CalendarContract.Events.InterfaceConsts.Dtstart, startTime);
        eventValues.Put(CalendarContract.Events.InterfaceConsts.Dtend, endTime);
        eventValues.Put(CalendarContract.Events.InterfaceConsts.AllDay, false);
        eventValues.Put(CalendarContract.Events.InterfaceConsts.HasAlarm, 1);
        eventValues.Put(CalendarContract.Events.InterfaceConsts.EventTimezone, Java.Util.TimeZone.Default.ID);
        eventValues.Put(CalendarContract.Events.InterfaceConsts.EventEndTimezone, Java.Util.TimeZone.Default.ID);

        var eventUri = Android.App.Application.Context.ContentResolver.Insert(EVENTS_URI, eventValues);
        long eventID = long.Parse(eventUri.LastPathSegment);

        ContentValues remindervalues = new ContentValues();
        remindervalues.Put(CalendarContract.Reminders.InterfaceConsts.Minutes, 60);
        remindervalues.Put(CalendarContract.Reminders.InterfaceConsts.EventId, eventID);
        remindervalues.Put(CalendarContract.Reminders.InterfaceConsts.Method, (int)Android.Provider.RemindersMethod.Alert);
        var reminderURI = Android.App.Application.Context.ContentResolver.Insert(CalendarContract.Reminders.ContentUri, remindervalues);
```

It's working good in all device, but when I try with Google pixel device, it gets exception while I insert the Remainder data

Comment: You are talking about an exception here. Can you at least tell us what the exception is?

Comment: Exception : 'Android.Database.Sqlite.SQLiteException' @Raimo

Comment: @Ajin, you said you project works fine in other device, but don' work on Google pixel, if the Google pixel device android version is higher 6.0, I suggest you check permission, must request permission atruntime, then about add event for calendar, you can take a look:http://www.nullskull.com/a/10478364/calendar-in-android-xamarin.aspx

Comment: I had already set the calendar permission

Comment: @Ajin, Can you provide one demo that can reproduce your issue at Github, I have one Google Pixel device, I will test it at my side.